# Generate javascript if run [DEBUG] mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, master-pages

Correctly I add **javascript** to the page?
Is there a special `System.Web.UI.Control` for these purposes?

code in Site.Mastre.cs:

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
    #if DEBUG
    Page.Header.Controls.Add
    (new LiteralControl("<script>" +
                        "alert(\"Hello! Run in [DEBUG] mode!\")");" +
                        "</script>"));
    #else
    Page.Header.Controls.Add
    (new LiteralControl("<script>" +
                        "alert(\"Hello! Run in [RELEASE] mode!\")");" +
                        "</script>"));
    #endif
    base.OnLoad(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207(v=vs.140).aspx)

You can use `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Type, String, String)` for this.

The example from the Microsoft Page:

```
String scriptText = "";
scriptText += "function DisplayCharCount(){";
scriptText += "   spanCounter.innerText = " + " document.forms[0].TextBox1.value.length";
scriptText += "}";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CounterScript", scriptText, true);
```